# chrome extension set underscore prefixed cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

i'm trying to set cookies such as `__Host`, `__Secure`, `__utma`  through the chrome extension

```
chrome.cookies.set({
"url":"https://*.google.com",
"name":"__Host-1PLSID",
"value":"s.IN|s.youtube:JAhqi_myqzIlEExBcYSrKg9DiCjl6XLANupheaB_cCsAO_SgGlCGlX7zCkQPDCf0A.",
"path":"/",
"domain":".google.com",
"expirationDate":1830365600000,
"secure":false,
"httpOnly":false,
}, function (cookie) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
    console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
});
```

however in console getting an error `Failed to parse or set cookie named "__Host-1PLSID".` for all cookies starting with `__`. All other cookies are set without errors (without the uderscore prefix).

What could be the possible reason?
Thanks!

Comment: `secure` must be true with `__host` and `__secure` cookies per the specification.

Comment: setting `secure` to true worked, but only for `__secure` cookies, still the same issue with `__host`

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie): it says you can't specify a domain.