# Set cookie whose name start by __Host- using the extension api of Chrome Web Store

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, setcookie

I have a Chrome Extension which allow to copy and paste cookies, but recently it's not working with cookies which the name start with `__Host`. I search for [similar cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74360115/chrome-extension-set-underscore-prefixed-cookies) and [the solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes) seems to write the cookies which start with `__Host` always as secure and without domain.

```
__Host- prefix: Cookies with names starting with __Host- must be set with the secure flag, must be from a secure page (HTTPS), must not have a domain specified (and therefore, are not sent to subdomains), and the path must be /.
```

But, when I execute:

```js
const cookieParams = { name: '__Host-XX', value: 'foo', secure: true, url: 'http://localhost:3000/' }
await chrome.cookies.set(cookieParams)
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Failed to parse or set cookie named "__Host-XXX".
```

The cookies can be created manually so I expect to be able to create the cookies programmatically but I don't find the way to do it.

Comment: The documentation says it must be a secure URL i.e. https, but yours is http.